# Error During C++ Compilation With Resource Files

Tags: c++, winapi, resources, compiler-errors

All right so I created a C++ Win32 program that worked fine. Then I wanted to use a custom icon so I created a "resource.h" file and a "resource.rc" file and I `#include`'d them both in my C++ source file. However on compilation I get the following error for line 3:

> expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

What am I doing wrong? Am I forgetting something?

My resource.h file:

```
#define IDI_MYICON 201
```

My resource.rc file:

```
#include "resource.h"

IDI_MYICON ICON "star.ico"
```

Finally the first three line (the ones with the problem) of my C++ Win32 file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"
#include "resource.rc"
```

Comment: Try not including your rc file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not supposed to include the .rc file into your source code, just the .h file.  You are supposed to compile the .rc file separately into a .res file using your development environment's resource compiler, and then link the .res file into the final executable.

Comment: how would I "link the .res file into the final executable"?

Comment: The details depend on your particular build environment, but in general you would link it in a similar way that you are linking in .obj and .lib files. If you are using VC++ or C++Builder, for instance, you can add the .rc file itself to your C++ project and let the IDE compile and link it for you.

Comment: I'm compiling from MinGW for command line which is why i've never heard of compiling or linking but I found a good tutorial on it so thanks Remy for setting me on the right track :)

Comment: C++ is a multi-stage language. Source files are preprocessed to parse precompiler macros, then the resulting code is compiled into intermediate files, which are then linked together to produce the final executable.

Answer (score 3):

You don't include `.RC` files into C++ files. You compile them with `RC.EXE` (the resource compiler). This generates a `.RES` file that you give to the linker along with your other `.OBJ` files.